# AJAX file upload giving undefined file error

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, upload

let me first explain what I aim to do, then display my code.

What I want to do is make a page which basically updates a user's details in the database, I did this part first and everything works perfectly here, through AJAX. Next I wanted to update the profile picture of the user as well through AJAX, so I made a normal file upload PHP page to make sure that my PHP code was working correctly and it was. Now I just needed to perform the upload via AJAX, and this is where I get stuck. I keep getting an error message from the PHP page which states `undefined index: file`.

Please feel free to ask any questions, and thank you for the responses.

Here is my HTML form:

```
<form action="upload.php?upload&type=profile" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <label for="profile">Profile Picture</label><br />
    <img id="preview" width="200" height="200" src="<?php echo $user->getProfile(); ?>" alt="Profile Picture Preview" /><br />
    <br />
    <input type="file" name="file" id="file" onchange="loadImage(this);" /><br />
    <label for="username">Username</label><br />
    <input type="text" name="username" id="username" value="<?php echo $user->getUsername(); ?>" /><br />
    <label for="email">Email Adress</label><br />
    <input type="text" name="email" id="email" value="<?php echo $user->getEmail(); ?>" /><br />
    <label for="bio">Biography</label><br />
    <textarea name="bio" id="bio" cols="40" rows="5"><?php echo $user->getBio(); ?></textarea><br />
    <label for="password">New Password</label><br />
    <input type="password" name="password" id="password" /><br />
    <label for="oldPass">Current Password</label><br />
    <input type="password" name="oldPass" id="oldPass" /><br />
    <label for="first">First Name</label><br />
    <input type="text" name="first" id="first" value="<?php echo $user->getFirstName(); ?>" /><br />
    <label for="last">Last Name</label><br />
    <input type="text" name="last" id="last" value="<?php echo $user->getLastName(); ?>" /><br />
    <br />
    <input type="submit" name="update" value="Save" id="update" />&nbsp;<input type="button" name="reset" value="Reset Fields" onclick="resetFields()" />
</form>
```

Here is my js file containing the AJAX:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#update").click(function() {
        profile = "pictures/default.jpg";
        username = $("#username").val();
        email = $("#email").val();
        bio = $("#bio").val();
        newPass = $("#password").val();
        oldPass = $("#oldPass").val();
        first = $("#first").val();
        last = $("#last").val();

        // First an ajax request to upload the image as it requires separate request
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "upload.php?upload&type=profile",
            data: new FormData(this),
            contentType: false,
            cache: false,
            processData: false,
            success: function(resp) {
                alert(resp);
            },
            error: function (resp) {
                alert(resp);
            }
        });

        // Now the updates in the profile
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "update.php",
            data: "mode=details&profile="+profile+"+&username="+username+"&email="+email+"&bio="+bio+"&password="+newPass+"&oldPass="+oldPass+"&first="+first+"&last="+last,
            success: function(resp) {
                // resp contains what is echoed on update.php
                alert(resp);
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

Finally, here is my PHP Code:

```
include "base.php";
// Kick user off this page if they are not logged in
if (!isset($user)) {
    echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0.1;url=index.php'>";
    exit();
}
if (isset($_GET['upload'])) {
    switch ($_GET['type']) {
        case "profile": {
            $dir = "pictures/";
            $maxFileSize = 2000000; // 2mb
            $extensions = array("jpg", "jpeg", "png", "gif");
            $currentPath = pathinfo($_FILES['file']['name']);
            $fileType = $currentPath['extension'];
            $targetFile = $dir.$user->getUsername()."Profile.".$fileType;
        }
        break;
        default: {
            echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0.1;url=index.php'>";
            exit();
        }
        break;
    }

    $upload = true;

    // Check the file size
    if ($_FILES['file']['size'] > $maxFileSize) {
        echo "The file is too large.";
        $upload = false;
    }

    // Limit file types
    if (!in_array($fileType, $extensions)) {
        echo "This file type is not allowed.";
        $upload = false;
    }

    // Check if file upload is allowed and upload if it is
    if ($upload) {
        if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $targetFile)) {
            echo basename($_FILES['file']['name']);
        } else {
            echo "There was an error during file upload.";
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code has a few issues. For one since your button was located within a `Form` and you were only associating a `click` on that button then the form was submitting itself as normal and pretty much confusing jquery. In order to capture the form properly in jquery you need to run it as a `submit` instead and add the `e.preventDefault();` so that your code in ajax runs instead of the actual form submitting on the page.

You need to add `e.preventDefault();` so that your form does not submit itself since you have `form` tags. Also change from `click` to `submit`

```
$("form").submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    profile = "pictures/default.jpg";
    username = $("#username").val();
    email = $("#email").val();
    bio = $("#bio").val();
    newPass = $("#password").val();
    oldPass = $("#oldPass").val();
    first = $("#first").val();
    last = $("#last").val();

    // First an ajax request to upload the image as it requires separate request
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "upload.php?upload&type=profile",
        data: new FormData(this),
        contentType: false,
        cache: false,
        processData: false,
        success: function(resp) {
            alert(resp);
        },
        error: function (resp) {
            alert(resp);
        }
    });

    // Now the updates in the profile
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "update.php",
        data: "mode=details&profile="+profile+"+&username="+username+"&email="+email+"&bio="+bio+"&password="+newPass+"&oldPass="+oldPass+"&first="+first+"&last="+last,
        success: function(resp) {
            // resp contains what is echoed on update.php
            alert(resp);
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

If you are dealing with multiple forms on a page, or dynamically created forms then you will want to use

```
$(document).on('submit', 'form', function(e) {
...
});
```

Even better give your form a class for dynamic data

```
$(document).on('submit', '.myform', function(e) {
...
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I understand the `e.preventDefault();` but any chance you can elaborate on changing from `click` to `submit`? Just want to understand to prevent future mistakes.

Comment: Thank you for elaborating on that, they're all in the same form but I understand what you're getting at.